# How to test devise API through Postman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, postman

I am new to Rails and have setup devise with a User model with email and password with also a React frontend. My aim is to consume the signup/signin endpoints in a React app instead of using the default Rails view. When I go to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up I can create an account and also see the data in PGadmin. However, I want to create a React based view for the forms and use the endpoint of the devise. I am trying to test the signup api using Postman but gives me an error `422 Unprocessable entity`. Not sure what params to pass in Rails.

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
```

Used:

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "test2@test.com",
        "password": "test"
    }
}
```

and

```
{   
        "email": "test2@test.com",
        "password": "test"
}
```

Comment: for sign_up you likely need to add a "password_confirmation" parameter. Check the parameters in the log in rails controller when you sign_up via a web form.

Comment: @dbugger Yea I added that too, but still gives the same error.

Comment: Does devise User have confirmable part (in your devise User config)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are in developement mode, so turn off the token authenticity (and turn on again if on product mode) for Postman requests, by add to app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

Then, config Postman like this:

- Type of request = POST
- Url = http://127.0.0.1:3000/users
- Body with form-data, with after keys, values

Key: user[email]. Value: test2@gmail.com

Key: user[password]. Value: secret

Key: user[password_confirmation]. Value: secret

Click on Send button you will bypass register page and get desire results (such as new user registration informations from Postgres if you not set the Confirmation mode in Devise User)!

Go on!

Comment: Thanks, for sending form data through a React app, should I be targeting http://127.0.0.1:3000/users or http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up ?

Comment: I don't use React, but I guess in this case you still to target `127.0.0.1:3000/users`, because it's the Rails server link!

Comment: @protoproto If we turn on the token authenticity in production, won't the request done by the React app fail because it is not passing the authenticity token?